# using stata svy subpopulation option for running regression

Tags: stata

My subpopulation is Asian females. When I add additional covariates to the model the number of observations in the subpopulation changes. Is there a way to create an indicator for the analytic sample that has complete observations for all the variables in the full specification when running regression with `svy subpop`?

```
gen asiansubpop1 = (nh_asian == 1 & female == 1)

svy, subpop(asiansubpop1==1): regress depressvar gen2 gen3 age 

svy, subpop(asiansubpop1==1): regress depressvar gen2 gen3 age educ bio1_step1 bio1 oth_fam
```

The number of observations for the subpopulation changes when I add additional covariates to the model. Is there a way to keep the analytical sample consistent across models?

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1746005-using-stata-svy-subpopulation-option-for-running-regression  Please note that is a request on Statalist and a very good idea here to tell people about cross-posting.